# How can I convert custom jquery event listener into angularjs listener?

Tags: angularjs, cornerstonejs

I have created `angularjs` component. I wrote a custom event listener in jquery, `event` is triggered by non-angularjs library.

```
$( "#myDiv" ).on( "CornerstoneImageRendered", function(e) {
   // buisness logic
});
```

myDiv is a `div` which is part of `angularjs` component.

I want to write this listener into `angularjs` component. How can I do it?

PS: Event link https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone/wiki/CornerstoneImageRendered-Event

Comment: What type of event is cornerstone?

Comment: @MarcusHöglund https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone/wiki/CornerstoneImageRendered-Event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom directive:

```
app.directive("myEventListener", function() {
    return {
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.on( "CornerstoneImageRendered", function(event) {
            // business logic
            scope.$eval(attrs.myEventListener, {$event: event});
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
});
```

### Usage

```
<div id="myDiv" my-event-listener="onMyEvent($event)">
</div>
```

### JS

```
$scope.onMyEvent = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
};
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to listen on events from an external, non angularjs, library you need to notify angularjs when a change has happend.
One way to do this is by wrapping your logic, which is triggered by the external event, in the **$scope.$apply** method. The $apply method will
notify angularjs that a change has happend and triggered the digest loop which will sync change from the scope to the view.

Add the event inside the controller and try it like this

```
$("#myDiv").on("CornerstoneImageRendered", function(e) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        // buisness logic on the scope
    });
});
```

[Here's](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) an great artile on the subject

Comment: what is the point in writing inner `$apply` event is getting triggered without that too. can't we use something like `$rootScope.$on`

Comment: @PabloEscobar listening on dom events is best done using jQuery. The problem which $apply solves is how to sync the changes made to angulajs. $rootScope is used inside of angularjs scopes, not outside of angularjs

Answer (score 0):

To archive what you want first you need use

**angular.element** and then you can add event listener